# Database Mail SQLServer 2008 and Outlook Sent Items folder

Tags: sql-server, exchange-server, database-mail

I have configured Database Mail for SQLServer 2008, I can send emails via our SMTP server, which use Exchange. The problem is that I want to store the sent messages in the Sent Items folder of the corresponding user, but the system is not doing that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable [Message Journaling](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998649.aspx) on your exchange server.